# Flutter google_maps_flutter can't able to change MapType by PopupMenuButton

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm just playing with new [Google Map](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) package of Flutter.

I want to change `MapType` of the map like, hybrid, satellite, none and etc by using of `PopupMenuButton`. Below are my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  List arrMapTyep = [
    {'title': 'none', 'value': MapType.none},
    {'title': 'hybrid', 'value': MapType.hybrid},
    {'title': 'normal', 'value': MapType.normal},
    {'title': 'satellite', 'value': MapType.satellite},
    {'title': 'terrain', 'value': MapType.terrain}
  ];
  MapType currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Google Map"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              initialValue: currentMapType,
              onSelected: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentMapType = value;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => _setupAllMapType()
              )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          options: GoogleMapOptions(
              mapType: currentMapType,
              compassEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(37.785834, -122.406417), 
                  zoom: 16,
                )
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }

  List<PopupMenuItem> _setupAllMapType() {
    List<PopupMenuItem> temArr = List();
    for (var i = 0; i < arrMapTyep.length; i++) {
      temArr.add(
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: arrMapTyep[i]['value'],
          child: Text(arrMapTyep[i]['title']),
        ),
      );
    }

    return temArr;
  }
}
```

I called `setState` but can work it.

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is too late to answer this, but in case someone like me stumbles upon this question;

Real time change in MapType, can be achieved using a setState() call upon currentMapType variable. I have implemented this in my application and it works smooth like butter!

Hope it helps. Happy Flutter'ing!

Quick reference (to change Normal map type to Satellite map type):

```
   RaisedButton(
     child: Text("Satellite"),
     onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
           currentMapType = MapType.satellite;
        });
     },
   )
```

Comment: I have a button in the appbar actions that is used to change the map type but doing so gives me : Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor

The map is a secondary widget